# How to create excel type tables in crystal report?

Tags: crystal-reports, c#-2.0, crystal-reports-2008

I am generating crystal report from c# code. My dataset has 10 columns. The data is dynamic. The report is generating fine with the data at runtime. But the format is the default crystal format without the tabular format. I want to display the data in table format like the tables in excel. How do I go about it?

Following is the code block I am using to generate crystal report.

```
using (ReportDocument rd = new ReportDocument())
        {
            CrystalReportFilePath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["crystal_report_file_path"];
            crystalReportFileName = "client_Details.rpt";
            pdfFileName = clientName + " - " + reportMonth + ".pdf";
            string rptFilePath = string.Format(@"{0}\{1}", CrystalReportFilePath, crystalReportFileName);
            rd.Load(rptFilePath);
            rd.SetDataSource(tempds);
            rd.ExportOptions.ExportFormatType = ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat;
            DiskFileDestinationOptions crDiskFileDestinationOptions = new DiskFileDestinationOptions();

            rd.ExportOptions.ExportFormatType = ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat;

            crDiskFileDestinationOptions.DiskFileName = string.Format(@"{0}\{1}", CrystalReportFilePath, pdfFileName);
            rd.ExportOptions.ExportDestinationOptions = crDiskFileDestinationOptions;
            rd.ExportOptions.ExportDestinationType = ExportDestinationType.DiskFile;
            rd.VerifyDatabase();
            rd.Export();

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are using crystal report 2008. In this version we don't have the tabular format. Instead we have to select the fields, assign borders to each field and arrange them in a tabular format. Its a pain but that's how it is.

And for different colors for alternate rows as in Excel, we have to write a formula in section expert -> details -> color tab

```
if RecordNumber mod 2 = 0 then Color (234, 234, 234) else crNoColor
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Shared Sub ExportDataSetToExcel(ByVal ds As DataTable, ByVal filename As String)
        Dim response As HttpResponse = HttpContext.Current.Response
        response.Clear()
        response.Buffer = True
        response.Charset = ""
        'response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
        response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"
        'response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=""" & filename & ".xls")

        Using sw As New StringWriter()
            Using htw As New HtmlTextWriter(sw)
                Dim dg As New DataGrid()
                dg.DataSource = ds
                dg.DataBind()
                dg.RenderControl(htw)
                response.Charset = "UTF-8"
                response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8
                response.BinaryWrite(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetPreamble())
                response.Output.Write(sw.ToString())
                response.[End]()
            End Using
        End Using
    End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Abdul rahman, thank you for your reply. I was looking for creating excel style tables in crystal report.